# "cannot open file" for perl under cygwin

Tags: perl, cygwin

I have following code which trying to write content into a log file:

```
sub write_log
{
  local( $f ) = "$log_dir/$log_file";
  $OUTPUT_FPATH = $f;
  print "$OUTPUT_FPATH \n";
  open( OUTPUT_FPATH, ">$f" ) ||
  die "Error: cannot open output file '$f'\n";
}
```

I can see the "OUTPUT_FPATH" point to the correct place like

```
/cygdrive/c/mylog/verify.log.
```

I also used "echo "test" > /cygdrive/c/mylog/verify.log" in the cygwin console directly which works fine

But why do I still get "cannot open ...." when I run the perl script?

And I am sure this code is tested, so it could be me doing something wrong, access right? or what else can it be?

Attached an simple example to reproduce the error:

```
eval '(exit $?0)' && eval 'exec perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
& eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 $argv:q'
        if $running_under_some_shell;


sub write_log
{
local( $f ) = "/cygdrive/c/test/log.log";
$RT_OUTPUT_FH = $f;
printf $f;
open( RT_OUTPUT_FH, ">$f" ) || die "Error: cannot open output file '$f' \n";
}


sub main
{
    write_log( "hahahaha" );
}

&main();
```

The same error with `"!$"` -> `no such file or directory`

while it still works like this in the cygwin promopt

```
    echo "hahahahahaha" > /cygdrive/c/test/log.log
```

Comment: Use the `$!` error reporting variable in your `die` message to find out why the open fails. E.g. `die "Cannot open $f: $!"` You should also know that ending the `die` message with newline `\n` suppresses the line number from being displayed in the die message.

Comment: @TLP got no such file or directory....

Comment: I am not familiar with how cygwin handles paths, but that seems to be a likely source of the error.

Comment: It seems like your OUTPUT_FPATH contains a dot at the end of the path.

Comment: You are doing something that is not correct to produce this error message. We cannot tell what that is from the information you have given. If you want more help, please produce a sample program with input that can be run to demonstrate your problem, a so called [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @TLP thanks for suggestion, yep, I am writing some simple test now

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there some reason to assign `$f` to `$OUTPUT_FPATH`?

Comment: I was wondering that as well, and it occurred to me that there is an archaic functionality with `open` that checks the global version of the file handle name, if no file name is given, e.g. :`$FOO = "file.txt"; open FOO; # actually works`. It is not the reason for your troubles, though.

Comment: What you might do is: `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper $f;` to see if the path contains any unwanted characters.

Comment: @mpapec No, it is the same functionality as the 2 argument version: `In the one- and two-argument forms of the call, the mode and
filename should be concatenated (in that order), preferably
separated by white space. You can--but shouldn't--omit the mode
in these forms when that mode is "<". It is always safe to use
the two-argument form of "open" if the filename argument is a
known literal.`

Comment: @TLP yes, correct. `perl -e '$F= ">write"; open F; print F 44'` Tempted to use it in one-liners.

Comment: @TLP added the simple example with hard coded path

Comment: Does this also works? `echo "hahahahahaha" > /cygdrive/c/test/log.log`

Comment: And if you run this, it dies with the error `No such file or directory`? It cannot print anything to your file, because 1) you are printing to STDOUT, 2) you print before you open the handle.

Comment: @mpapec  yep, the echo in the prompt works just fine. And I can see the data in the log.log with cat after

Comment: @mpapec sorry, tying error, type it in wrong oder

Comment: Please be careful with the details. We need to rely on that you do what you say you do. Also, `echo /cygdrive/c/test/log.log > "hahahahahaha"` is not the same as `echo "hahahahahaha" > /cygdrive/c/test/log.log` Are you sure you did the latter and not the former? You said you did the former.

Comment: @ I realized I typed wrong when @mpapec answered. You know, I cannot copy command line from cygwin..... need to type again.... yep, but I am sure I can see the data in the log.log , i even changed the characters and re-do the operation

Comment: Ok, next step: `perl -Mautodie -e 'open F, ">/cygdrive/c/test/log.log"; print F 44'`

Comment: @mpapec Can't open<'F', '/cygdrive/c/test/log.log'>: No such file or directory at -e line 1

But I find something, forgot to mention I switch to cygwin from visual studio prompt, running "c:\cygwin\cygwin.bat" from visual studio prompt, and I just tried the test from original cygwin, it doesn't give me error then. It shall be windows/cygwin format difference for the path.....

Comment: cannot notify two users at one comment, @TLP please see comment above.....

Comment: Ok, so you have two completely different cygwin environments, and each has his own idea of your directory paths.

Answer (score 0):

> And I am sure this code is tested, so it could be me doing something wrong, access right? or what else can it be?

Verify that the `perl` invoked is indeed the Perl from CygWin.

The error you are seeing makes only sense in case if you have, in addition to CygWin, also native Windows Perl installed.

CygWin's Perl understands `/cygdrive/` paths - native Windows Perl doesn't.

To tell one from another, try for example `system("ls /")`: CygWin and Windows have different understanding of the root directory (and Windows doesn't have `ls` command).